# Referencing auto-generated JavaScript files from TypeScript in Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, typescript

I am developing a web application in Visual Studio 2012 and I have a solution with a few projects. Also, I am using the TypesScript plugin (version 1.0RC) and I would like to keep all TypeScript development in a separate project while only referencing the auto-generated JavaScript files in projects that actually need to use them. To do so, I have tried a couple of approaches but I'm not completely satisfied with none of them.

Consider the directory tree of the two projects below:

```
WebProject
|
– /img
– /includes
– /js
– index.html
– web.config

TypeScriptProject
|
– file1.ts
– file2.ts
```

I want to keep the updated version of all auto-generated JavaScript files from `TypeScriptProject` (in this case, `file1.js` and `file2.js`) inside the `js` folder of `WebProject`. Here's what I've tried so far:

1. **Adding the JavaScript files as a regular file in `WebProject`**: this doesn't work since a new copy of the file is created in the `js` folder. This new copy won't reflect future changes made to the original TypeScript file.
2. **Adding the auto-generated JavaScript files as a link in `WebProject`**: this seemed to work at first using some [specific settings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21717283/537323), but then I realized that it doesn't work in all environments for some reason I am not aware of yet.

If anyone has a better solution in mind (or in use), it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from VS 2013 Update 2 RC, now you can edit a TypeScript project settings in order to do exactly what was described in the question.

To do so, go to the project properties, then select the `TypeScript Build` tab. In the `Output` area, check the option `Redirect JavaScript output to directory` and define which directory you want to copy your JavaScript files to.

Answer (score 0):

You could use grunt-ts with the `--outDir` option  : https://github.com/grunt-ts/grunt-ts#compiler-support

Here is a sample grunt file to get you started: https://github.com/grunt-ts/grunt-ts/blob/master/sample/Gruntfile.js